# Packet Count Using Scapy in Python

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

I am capturing the ICMP packets from a specific IP address using:

```python
import scapy.all from *

sniff(filter="icmp and src host 192.168.100.3 and dst host 192.168.100.2", prn=lambda x: x.sprintf("%IP.proto% packets from %IP.src% to %IP.dst%"))
```

I am getting the following output:

```
icmp packets from 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.2
icmp packets from 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.2
icmp packets from 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.2
icmp packets from 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.2
icmp packets from 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.2
...
```

However, I only want to display the total number of packets captured
in real time i.e.

```
Total icmp packets from 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.2 is <total_packets>
```

This above line should also be updated regularly i.e. I only want this line at all times in my output. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to modify this line:

```
sniff(filter="icmp and src host 192.168.100.3 and dst host 192.168.100.2", prn=lambda x: x.sprintf("%IP.proto% packets from %IP.src% to %IP.dst%"))
```

The `lambda x: x.sprintf("%IP.proto% packets from %IP.src% to %IP.dst%"` function runs for every request

So something like:

```
import os
counter = 0
def deal_with_packets(x):
    global counter
    os.system("cls")
    ips = x.sprintf("Total icmp packets from %IP.src% to %IP.dst%")
    counter += 1
    print(ips + "is" + str(counter))
    
sniff(filter="icmp and src host 192.168.100.3 and dst host 192.168.100.2", prn=lambda x: deal_with_packets(x))
```

Use `os.system("cls")` on Windows, `os.system("clear")` on Linux and macOS

Comment: Thanks. Just two things I wanna mention: First: Wrap counter in str() in the print() statement. Second: Replace "cls" with "clear" for Linux. Don't know about windows though.

Comment: Also, counter+=1 should be above the print statement otherwise it shows one less packet.

Comment: @MRA1412 You're right about the print statement, it was an oversight

Comment: In Windows it is indeed cls